# default value for the settings that not mentioned in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I have a VPS with php and mysql. my.cnf file does not contains the line " long_query_time ". Then what is the default value for this parameter?? Will I be able to run queries which take 20 minutes in this VPS??

Comment: what about checking mysql docs?

Comment: [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time

Answer (score 0):

You possibly cannot find the *default* value unless you could inspect the source code and build settings used by whoever produced the MySQL binaries your VPS is using. And I don't think you need it anyway: just inspect the *current* value and decide whether it suits your need:

```
mysql> select @@long_query_time;
+-------------------+
| @@long_query_time |
+-------------------+
|         10.000000 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

To answer your other question:

> Will I be able to run queries which take 20 minutes in this VPS??

That has nothing to do with the [aforementioned directive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time), which does nothing but control logging:

> If a query takes longer than this many seconds, the server increments
>   the Slow_queries status variable. If the slow query log is enabled,
>   the query is logged to the slow query log file.